# Async success function being called after page redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This function is called after an ajax get request gets results back

```
function handleLogin() {
    if ($("#imalogin").length) {
        alert("Your login has expired, please log back in");
        window.location.replace("login.aspx");
    }
}
```

This is a function that calls it

```
function addEstablishments() {
    $.get(encodeURI("addEstablishment.aspx?locationCode=" + $('#locationCode').val()), function (data) {
        $("#dbCheck").html(data);
        handleLogin();
    }).done(function (){
        if ($("#duplicateEstablishment").length) {
            $("#locationCodeError").html("Location code already used")
        }
        else {
            alert("Location added");
            getEstablishments();
            hideLocationForm();
        }
    }).fail(function () { 
        alert("Failed to add location. Please try again in a few seconds"); 
        $("#locationAddressError").html("Could not confirm address"); 
    });
}
```

I would "expect" `handleLogin` to show the alert inside of it, which it does, and then redirect immediately and the rest of the code would not execute. But this is the strange land of javascript, so the alert in the `.done` event of `addEstablishments` fires as well before it redirects, so people get a message that it has been added when it has not, and they get redirected to a login page, log in and find out it was never added. So there is some obscure javascript rule that I'm not aware of or is this because I can't call `handleLogin` where I am, and need to call it in .done?

Comment: I see `addEstablishments()` being defined, and not called.

Comment: If I edit to add more code, to show the entire trail of how things get called, as requested, it's going to be a about 5 different methods that lead up to what I posted. Does the requester still want to see all of that code?

Comment: the callback of `$.get` is the same thing as `done`. Why use both? Combine the 2 and problem likely disappears

Comment: @charlieftl I think that's actually the issue. In effect there are two callbacks being executed at the same time, hence the doubling up of the `alert()` calls

Comment: yes, this sounds right. I probably shouldn't bother with the .done and only invoke .fail  since I'm doing all of the work anyway in the anonymous callback function. I'll try that.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan JS is single-threaded, not multi-threaded, so it can only process statements sequentially (or synchronously). This means that two callbacks cannot be executed at the same time. One is being executed first, the other is being executed second. The issue is that by making a location assignment, an asynchronous event has been initiated by JS in the browser. The browser is now handling the location assignment, making HTTP requests and waiting for a server response before it redirects to the new location. In the mean time, the JS thread can continue with execution of the next callback

Comment: That's a more complete answer where it might be more helpful to those who read this later, and I realize what people are telling me. Can you write that as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The `location.replace` initiates an async process

JavaScript is single-threaded, not multi-threaded, so it can only process statements sequentially (or synchronously). Contrary to some comments here, this means that two callbacks cannot be executed at the same time. One is being executed first, the other is being executed second.

The issue is that by making a location assignment, an asynchronous process has been initiated by JavaScript in the browser. *The browser is now handling the location assignment*: making HTTP requests and waiting for a server response before it redirects to the new location.

In the mean time, the JavaScript thread can continue executing the next callback. So, the second alert can appear before the page redirect is completed by the browser.

### Define `.done()` conditionally inside your first callback

To redirect the page in your first success handler without your secondary `done()` handler executing, define it conditionally inside your first handler.

```js
function handleLogin() {
 if ($("#imalogin").length) {
   alert("Your login has expired, please log back in");
   
   // async process initiated
   window.location.replace("login.aspx");
   
   // this returns true before the async location redirect completes
   return true; 
 } else {
   return false;
 }
}

$.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', function(data, status, jqxhr) {
  $("#dbCheck").html(JSON.stringify(data));
  
  // If handleLogin returns false…
  if(!handleLogin()) {
    
    // …assign second success handler.
    // (This never gets assigned if handleLogin returns true.)
    jqxhr.done(function(data) { 
      alert('second success');
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="imalogin" disabled /><br />
<code id="dbCheck"></code>
```

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded, not multi-threaded, so it can only process statements sequentially (or synchronously), really?! good to know

Answer (score 0):

you need to look at jquery documentation, you passed

```
function (data) {
    $("#dbCheck").html(data);
    handleLogin();
}
```

as $.get second argument , so it is called on ajax success, and again you have used done function with another function as it's argument.

this is from jquery documentation:

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
  var jqxhr = $.get( "example.php", function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
  });
```

Comment: so essentially, handleLogin has to be called after the entire get request, along with it's done and fail methods have been called

Comment: i don't know if you should do that or not, it depends on your business but the point is, you are invoking two callbacks, so you should decide what to do.